# Android studio click Listview and set view

Tags: java, android, listview

I am trying to show the view selected when user click on it, but it always gets other views after scroll. Here is the picture below. 
[image: I selected one.]

[image: After I scrolled, there is another]

```
final String[] str = new String[]{MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE, MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST};
    final int[] displayViews = new int[]{R.id.music_name};
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.music_item, cursor, str, displayViews, CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);
    music_list.setAdapter(adapter);

music_list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        int select_item = -1;

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, final View view, final int i, long l) {

            if ((select_item == -1) || (select_item == i)) {
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                index = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("TITLE"));
                music_list1.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                Log.d("i",";:"+i);
            } else {
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                view2.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE); 
                index = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("TITLE"));
                music_list1.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            }
            view2 = view; 
            select_item = i; 
        }
    });
```

Comment: (select_item == i) is always true

Answer (score 1):

`i` is a position used by adapter for views visible  within the screen so instead of `i` use `l` which is a unique row id for every row

```
if ((select_item == -1) || (select_item == l)) {//...}
else{//..}
select_item = l;
```